# How to assign a picture to the UIImageView (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to add an image from the gallery to the new ViewController, but get an error

> Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let im = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editImage") as! EditImageViewController
            vc.imageView.image = im
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Something went wrong")
    }
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `EditImageViewController.imageView`is nil.
To pass image from outside, you need to add UIImage property to `EditImageViewController`.

To assign that image to `UIImageView`, use `viewDidLoad()`

Something like this:

```
class EditImageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var imageToAdd: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imageView.image = imageToAdd
    }
}
```

To pass image to new controller, just set `imageToAdd`, so `vc.imageView.image = im` becomes `vc.imageToAdd = im`

Comment: To expand on this answer, in general, no outside code should ever directly access views of a view controller. Outside code should only provide information/data to the view controller. Let the view controller be responsible for updating its own views based on data. That's one of the points behind MVC design.